# C++ conversion from int to non-scalar type in a simple vector program

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, double, cout

I just want you to tell you that I am writing this post after reading many postings regarding the error I've been getting : " conversion from ‘int’ to non-scalar type." But for my own program, I don't get to apply any of the answers out there to fix it. I hope any of you can give me a comment/opinion/suggestion or concern on the following specific code.

```
    vector<double>::iterator a = *max_element(vector1.begin(), vector1.end());
    vector<double>::iterator b  = *min_element(vector1.begin(), vector1.end());
    vector<double>::iterator c  = *(nth_element(vector1.begin(), vector1.begin() + vector1.siz
```

And one last quick question: Isn't the following way correct to print out the value of variable a, b, c respectively? My compiler is saying that there is no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘std::cout << a....'. I would appreciate your feedback on this too.

```
cout << a << b << c << endl;
```

Thank you so much!
 I will keep watching on this until getting your reply.

The following is my code for your consideration

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>
 #include <algorithm>
 #include <vector>

 using namespace std;

int main(){

ifstream ifs("foo.txt");


//initiailize a vector of integers:
vector<int> vector1;

double d;
while(ifs >> d)
{
    vector1.push_back(d);
}

int allnumb = vector1.size();

for(int i = 0; i < allnumb; i++){

    vector<double>::iterator a = *max_element(vector1.begin(), vector1.end());
    vector<double>::iterator b  = *min_element(vector1.begin(), vector1.end());
    vector<double>::iterator c  = *(nth_element(vector1.begin(), vector1.begin() + vector1.size()/2, vector1.end()));
    cout << a << b << c << endl;

    }

   return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`max_element` and the other functions return iterators. You then use `*` to dereference those to get the `int` values they refer to, and finally try to use those `int` values to initialise a different iterator type. That makes no sense, hence the first error.

Then you try to print the iterators, which aren't printable, hence the second error.

Perhaps you want the values:

```
int a = *max_element(...);
int b = *min_element(...);
int c = *nth_element(...);
cout << a << ' ' << b << ' ' << c << endl; // add spaces for readability
```

or perhaps you want correctly-typed iterators:

```
vector<int>::iterator a = max_element(...);
auto b = min_element(...);  // a more convenient alternative, since C++11
auto c = nth_element(...);
cout << *a << ' ' << *b << ' ' << *c << endl; // dereference to print the values
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in your code.
1. `std::vector<int>` is declared, but `std::vector<double>::iterator` is used. What is correct type - int or double?
2. max_element() and min_element() return `std::vector<Type>::iterator` and your are trying to derefference iterator on the right side and assign its value to iterator variable type on the left side. Use `int a = *max_element(vector1.begin(), vector1.end());`
3. nth_element() does not return anything. Use `nth_element(vector1.begin(), vector1.begin() + vector1.size()/2, vector1.end());`

Answer (score -2):

It looks like there are some issues in your code. The iterators a, b, and c should be used to access values, not printed directly. Additionally, the loop structure is causing the same values to be printed in each iteration. Here is the corrected code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream ifs("foo.txt");

    // initialize a vector of doubles:
    vector<double> vector1;

    double d;
    while (ifs >> d) {
        vector1.push_back(d);
    }

    int allnumb = vector1.size();

    // Check if the vector is not empty
    if (!vector1.empty()) {
        vector<double>::iterator a = max_element(vector1.begin(), 
vector1.end());
        vector<double>::iterator b = min_element(vector1.begin(), 
vector1.end());
        nth_element(vector1.begin(), vector1.begin() + vector1.size() / 2, 
vector1.end());
        vector<double>::iterator c = vector1.begin() + vector1.size() / 2;

        cout << "Max Element: " << *a << endl;
        cout << "Min Element: " << *b << endl;
        cout << "Median Element: " << *c << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Vector is empty." << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code reads values from "foo.txt" into a vector, then it finds the max, min, and median elements using the max element, min element, and nth element functions, respectively. The corrected code now properly prints the values of the max, min, and median elements.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy